# POST doesn't get filled

Tags: php, post

**Problem**

I am filling up a POST, whenever I click on the submit button, and it should set the POST.
but unfortunately, for some random reason it doesn't fill the POST.

**The code**

```
        echo '
        <form action="settings.php" method="POST">
        <textarea name="area" class="input" id="textarea">'.$settings_welcome_page['paragraph'].'</textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="button">
        </form>';

        if (isset($_POST['area'])) {
            $update = $CONNECT_TO_DATABASE->prepare("UPDATE welcome_text SET paragraph = :message");
            $update->bindValue(':message', $_POST['paragraph']);
            $update->execute();
            header ('Location: settings.php?status=sucess');    
        } else {
            echo' post not working ';
        }
```

It is returning the echo 'Post not working'. which means that the POST 'area' is not set.

What is the problem? How do I fix? Thanks.

Comment: What does var_dump($_POST); show? And i hope your form and your query arn't on the same page.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: You have form and query on same page ?

Comment: What is the page name?

Comment: I guess you're filling the form correctly, but you just get redirected immediatly (Loosing POST) and as @Kaii mentionned, you're not inserting the correct value into your database, so you can't see any changes. Try removing that `header` and do a `echo 'worked';` instead

Comment: It is nice to see PHP code that is not using `mysql_` and that has a design; the relocate prevents accidental reloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_POST['paragraph']
```

should be

```
$_POST['area']
```

in binding the value also in your condition you may ad

```
if(isset($_POST['area']) || (isset($_GET['status']) == 'success')){
    // code here..
} 
else{
   // code here..
}
```

for you to see if you already submitted the form and not falling into else.

IN General..your code should look like this

```
if (isset($_POST['area']) || (isset($_GET['status']) == 'succes')) {
            $update = $CONNECT_TO_DATABASE->prepare("UPDATE welcome_text SET paragraph = :message");
            $update->bindValue(':message', $_POST['area']);
            $update->execute();
            header ('Location: settings.php?status=sucess');    
        } else {
            echo' post not working ';
        }
```

Comment: That's not the problem here.

Comment: The point ist the "if (isset($_POST['area']))" because he gets the output "post not working"

Comment: My point is at first it when he submitted this will work but data will not been updated then he redirect it thats why it will fall on else condition after being redirection

Comment: Thank you, it is the problem. Works fine now. I just forgot to edit the paragraph to 'area', I have like 3 of these running. I should be more specific next time!

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens:

1. You fill in the form and click "Edit",
2. Form gets POSTed and puts data in database,
3. You relocated to the same page, but **without** POST (by calling the `header` function).
4. Your page shows up, with no POST, rendering "Post not working".

To fix, remove the `header()` call, and it will not reload.

That, and refer to the right index: `$_POST['area']` instead of `$_POST['paragraph']`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your server will answer the POST by a redirection header:

```
   if (isset($_POST['area'])) {
        header ('Location: settings.php?status=sucess');    
    } else {
        echo' post not working ';
    }
```

When the browser receive this header, a `GET settings.php?status=sucess` is sent to the server.
It's why you receive the `post not working` message.

If you try this code, you will see that your POST is working well:

```
<html><body><?php 
 echo '
     <form action="settings.php" method="POST">
       <textarea name="area" class="input" id="textarea">bla bla ...</textarea><br />
       <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="button">
     </form>';

    if (isset($_POST['area'])) {
        echo' this was a POST of area='.$_POST['area'];
    } else {
        echo' this was a GET ';
    }
?></body></html>
```